# How to show there exists no solution to a discrete logarithm problem on an Elliptic Curve?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

**The exact problem is to show that $\nexists$k such that $k(1,2) = (4,5)$ on the elliptic curve defined by $\widetilde{E}: y^2 = x^3 -14x + 17$ over $\mathbb Q$.**

Background:
E: $y^2 = x^3 + 3$ over $F_7$. On E we have 4(1,2) = (4,5).
Now the points P = (1,2) and Q = (4,5) are on both E and $\widetilde{E}$ and $\widetilde{E}$ was found by uplifting E (from mod 7 to Q). Also it was discovered that 2(1,2) = (1,-2) and 3(1,2) = $\infty $ mod 73 on $\widetilde{E}$.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to use the information given by the previous parts of the problem is supposed to help solve the problem. I obviously can't use computation to show this since there exists an infinite number of values of k in the integers. I can only see using  a proof by contradiction, but what steps to take?

Comment: In case it is still not clear: for $E/\mathbb Q$, we have discriminant $\Delta$. For each prime $p\nmid\; \Delta$, you have a reduction mod $p$ by reducing each point $P=(x,y)$ to $$\tilde P=(x,y)\pmod p=(\tilde x,\tilde y)$$ (and $E$ too). So if indeed $[k](1,2)= (4,5)$, you have $[k](\tilde 1,\tilde 2)=(\tilde 4,\tilde 5)$ in $\mathbb F_p$ (same addition formula). So it suffices to generate $\langle \tilde P\rangle$ over $\mathbb F_p$ and check if any element matches $(\tilde 4,\tilde 5)$. You can do this for infinitely many $p$ and chances are one of them works if $[k](1,2)\neq (4,5)$.

Comment: As for the comment from Álvaro, the idea: you can check if $(1,2)$ and $(4,5)$ are torsion points (Nagell-lutz theorem). If both are torsion, then there are only finitely many points to check.  Otherwise, $(1,2)$ is non torsion and you can investigate $[k](1,2)= (x_k,y_k)$. The point is that for sufficiently large $k$, we have $$\max\{x_{k+1},y_{k+1}\}> \max\{x_k,y_k\}$$ so the coordinates is always growing. You can find a $k$ such that in addition $\max\{x_k,y_k\}> \max\{4,5\}=5$. Then for $i\geq k$ we cannot have $[i](1,2)=(4,5)$ by comparing the values. Finally, check for $1\leq i\leq k$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have found that modulo $73$, $(1,2)$ is a point of order $3$.
Since $(4,5)$ modulo $73$ is neither $(1,2),(1,-2)$ nor $\infty$, it can't be in the group generated by $(1,2)$.

You should try to compute the group of the curve reduced modulo a few primes and find primes  other than $73$ where the reduction of $(4,5)$ is not in the subgroup generated by the reduction of $(1,2)$.

Comment: Wait so the points (1,2),(1,-2), $\infty$ exhaust all the possible sums of (1,2) modulo 73?
If for example I added (1,2) to itself 100 times in Q and then reduced that modulo 73 I should get one of those 3 points above?

Comment: @AdamStaples : yes ! can you compute the first few multiples and check ?

Comment: 2*E1![1,2]; = 
(89/16 : 675/64 : 1) =
(1 : -2 : 1) Modulo 73

-------------------


3*E1![1,2]; = 
(-16271/5329 : 2175766/389017 : 1) = $\infty$ modulo 73

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use canonical heights on $E$. By the properties of canonical heights $\hat{h}(kQ)=k^2\cdot \hat{h}(Q)$, for any $Q\in E(\mathbb{Q})$ and any $k\geq 1$. Thus, if $k\cdot (1,2) = (4,5)$, it follows that $k^2\cdot \hat{h}(1,2)=\hat{h}(4,5)$, but
$$\hat{h}(1,2)= 1.14638174824\ldots, \text{ and } \hat{h}(4,5)=1.15045975869,$$
so $k^2\cdot \hat{h}(1,2)=\hat{h}(4,5)$ is impossible for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Using heights you can do a little better, and check that there are no $n$ and $m$ integers such that $n\cdot (1,2)=m\cdot (4,5)$. Any such $\mathbb{Z}$-linear relation would be picked up by the height matrix of $(1,2)$ and $(4,5)$. More concretely, if $P$ and $Q$ are rational points, we define $\langle P,Q\rangle = \hat{h}(P+Q)-\hat{h}(P)-\hat{h}(Q)$ and a matrix
$$H=\left(\begin{array}{cc}  \langle P,P\rangle & \langle P,Q\rangle \\
\langle Q,P\rangle & \langle Q,Q\rangle \end{array} \right),$$
and there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $P$ and $Q$ (modulo torsion) if and only if the determinant of $H$ is zero. However, for $P=(1,2)$ and $Q=(4,5)$ the determinant of $H$ is $1.15092709663\ldots \neq 0$, and therefore $P$ and $Q$ are independent.